# how to use javascript to drag&drop the div for touch screen

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, touch

how to use javascript to drag&drop the div for touch screen(not iphone or ipad.It owns traditional browser like IE6 but operate by fingers)？

on that device,fingers==mouse?

I used onmousedown/onmousemove for traditional page,but will it still work on that touch screen?

the code can still well work?if not,how to use it?

Comment: so what happens when you try it?

Comment: Assuming it's still a Windows OS with a touch screen as pointing device, the "touch" event is the same as click, and the rest should still be the same.

Comment: Why the fancy question mark in your first question? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Joseph thank you,so drag&drop uses with onmousedown&onmousemove?

Comment: @yobin afaik, there is no special touch events on those systems (except maybe hardware specific), unlike the smart phones today. normal mouse events should work, depending on the device.

Comment: @Alnitak my project will uses that mode,but I can't try it because without the device

Answer (score 0):

There are no special js events for drag and drop.
You existing code for drag and drop using the mouse might work (probably with some quirks).
It all depends on how good your touchscreen monitor translates human touches to mouse events.